# iOS while-loop reverting index back to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, while-loop

I have a game with a board with 26 tiles. The player rolls a number between 1 and 12, and the player then moves that many tiles. I do this by having an array (indexes 0-25) of the tiles, in order. This is my way of moving the player across the tiles (this contains code from Sprite Kit, which I know is under NDA, but the question isn't about that)

```
NSInteger rolled_number = arc4random() % 12;
while (rolled_number == 0)
    rolled_number = arc4random() % 12;
NSLog(@"%d", rolled_number);
NSInteger new_index = self.player1.currentTileIndex + rolled_number;
if (!(new_index <= 25))
    new_index = new_index - 26;
NSMutableArray *actions = [NSMutableArray array];
while (self.player1.currentTileIndex < new_index) {
    SKSpriteNode *node = [_tiles objectAtIndex:self.player1.currentTileIndex];
    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:node.position duration:1];
    [actions addObject:move];
    NSLog(@"currentTileIndex: %d", self.player1.currentTileIndex);
    if (self.player1.currentTileIndex + 1 > 25)
        self.player1.currentTileIndex -= 26;
    else
        self.player1.currentTileIndex++;
}
```

the problem with this code is if the player is on the tile at index `23` and rolls a `5`, they should go to the tile at index `3`, but instead it doesn't move, because it will instead make the `currentTileIndex` property `28` instead of `3`. My question is how can I modify this while-loop so that it will still work even when the number has to go to `0` instead of `26`?

Comment: I always thought the if loop was if (condition) { }. I dont know if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to get a number from 1 to 12 do:

```
NSInteger rolled_number = arc4random_uniform(12) + 1;
```

Then make proper use of the modulo operator to wrap your numbers:

```
NSInteger new_index = self.player1.currentTileIndex + rolled_number;
NSMutableArray *actions = [NSMutableArray array];
while (self.player1.currentTileIndex < new_index) {
    SKSpriteNode *node = _tiles[self.player1.currentTileIndex % _tiles.count];
    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:node.position duration:1];
    [actions addObject:move];
    NSLog(@"currentTileIndex: %d", self.player1.currentTileIndex % _tiles.count);
    self.player1.currentTileIndex++;
}

self.player1.currentTileIndex = self.player1.currentTileIndex % _tiles.count;
```

Comment: This helps, but the character still can't move if `self.player1.currentTileIndex` passes `25`. Even here, `new_index` can pass 25, and then `currentTileIndex` will increment past the bounds of my array.

Comment: The code I posted will work. Example. `currentTileIndex` is 22 and the player rolls a 10. `new_index` will be 32. The loop will iterate through. When `currentTileIndex` becomes 26, the expression `self.player1.currentTileIndex % _tiles.count` will give you 0 as desired. After the loop, the index is reset using the `%` operator so the next roll starts with a value from 0 - 25.

Comment: I just tested this, and in one case the `currentTileIndex` was 23. When I rolled next, it was a 9, but the while loop never executed, and the player never moved.

Comment: This will only work if it is acceptable for `self.player1.currentTileIndex` to ever exceed the maximum index, even for a brief moment. Since it is a property, maybe the setter assumes it is < 26?

Comment: @Krumelur Then a local variable can be used in its place for the loop. Either way, using the `%` operator to access the array element makes the logic here much easier.

Comment: This was correct, I forgot to remove a line of code that subtracted 26 from `new_index` if it was larger than 25. Thanks a lot.